# How to get Electron windows binding for sqlite3 on mac?

Tags: sqlite, electron, electron-builder

I'm on my Mac OS X computer.

I want to rebuild sqlite3 in my new Electron version.

When I use this command with electron-builder :

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3
```

It creates the file :
./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/electron-v4.1-darwin-x64/node_sqlite3.node

All works fine when executing my app on mac.

But I also need a sqlite3 binding for Windows...

When I execute my compiled app on Windows, I get this error :

```
Error: Cannot find module ... ... \node_sqlite3.node
```

Which command should I use with electron-rebuild?

Comment: You can't. Either use vm or real, you need to rebuild binary on windows.

Comment: I have chosen Electron because I could use only one code to compile for all platforms at the same time... And now, you say to me that I will have to use Electron on a second computer with Windows.... I'm sad!... :(

Comment: Electron is cross-platform code, but node native addon is not. That's not electron's limitation, limitation of node native addon.

Comment: Do you think I could get a PC, install electron, install sqlite3, rebuild electron qith sqlite3 and after copy the new 'node_sqlite3.node' file (for PC) on my mac?